# WPF : Easing Function with Cubic Bezier Curve like in CSS

Tags: c#, wpf, easing

My goal is to reproduce this mouse over animation in WPF :
https://xaalek.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2022-03-21-n3xl2.html?bypass-cache=74310593

Currently I have something like this in my code :

```
var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(280)))
{
    FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd,
    EasingFunction = new CubicEase()
};
```

But the result is not perfect.
Is it possible to create a custom easing with a Cubic Bezier Curve like in CSS ?

```
transition: box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1)
```

I saw that we can create custom Easing Function by inheriting
[EasingFunctionBase](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.easingfunctionbase?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

I need to specify the coordinates of points on the curve to get the same result.
https://cubic-bezier.com/#.4,0,.2,1

I could create a Custom Easing Function like this :

```
internal class MaterialEasingFunction : EasingFunctionBase
    {
        public MaterialEasingFunction()
            : base()
        {
            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut;
        }

        protected override double EaseInCore(double normalizedTime) => Math.Pow(normalizedTime, 3);

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() => new MaterialEasingFunction();

    }
```

But I don't know how I can specify the coordinates of the points on the curve.

Do you have any idea how I could do this?

Comment: `Math.Pow(normalizedTime, 3)` would be what CubicEase does. Your derived class would have to define properties for the additional control points and evaluate this function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves

Comment: When you define the function yourself, you would only use `EasingMode.EaseIn`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.easingmode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: @Clemens Ok so if I understand correctly instead of Math.Pow I have to put the equation of the cubic function right?

Comment: But in the equation there are 4 points, in CSS we only use 2 points how can I adapt this?

Comment: (0,0) and (1,1) are implicit.

Comment: Yeah I just saw it right here https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try to do this

Comment: Before you start, try CubicEase with EaseInOut first. That's very similar to what you seem to need.

Comment: I found out that we can accelerate and decelerate animation. I think if I put `AccelerationRatio = 0.4` and `DecelerationRatio = 0.2` on my `DoubleAnimation` it can do the job https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-accelerate-or-decelerate-an-animation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `AccelerationRatio` and `DecelerationRatio` properties on a `DoubleAnimation` :
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-accelerate-or-decelerate-an-animation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 
This is the CSS syntax for cubic bezier :

```
cubic-bezier(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

In this case, we just using `x1` and `x2`.
Since the coordinates go from 0 to 1, we can use the x-coordinates of the points as acceleration and deceleration ratios

This is the final result :

```
var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
{
    To = 1,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(280)),
    FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd,
    EasingFunction = new CubicEase(),
    AccelerationRatio = 0.4,
    DecelerationRatio = 0.2
};
```

Comment: This is however something different than what was asked for in the question.

Comment: I didn't know that acceleration and deceleration ratios existed. I thought the animation system would be similar to the one in CSS. In the end, with the ratios, it produces the same result as my CSS demo. CubicEase with EaseInOut produced a close result but not exactly the same. That's why I looked for another solution. But thank you for offering different solutions to my problem.